# java - Cant click button in frame

Tags: java, button, canvas

I have been trying to make a button for my program but for some reason I can't click it.

The program is a space invaders game where the gameplay is, for the most part, implemented. However I have decided to create a main menu, and have gotten stuck on getting to button to fully work.

I have been playing around with it for a while, but every time the user clicks where the button is, nothing happens. There is no animation for holding down the left mouse.

Yet when tab is pressed, the button can be highlighted, and can be pressed with the space space.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JButton startgamebutton = new JButton("Start Game");
    startgamebutton.setBounds(200, 500, 400, 50);

    JComponent component = frame.getRootPane();
    Main main = new Main();
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();

    frame.add(main);
    frame.setTitle("Space Invaders");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    cp.add(startgamebutton);
    cp.add(main);
    main.Start();
    startgamebutton.setBounds(200, 500, 400, 50);
    startgamebutton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        if (e.getSource() == startgamebutton) {
                System.out.println("start button Pressed ");
                }}
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, as you grab a reference to the root pane for no reasons, add `main` to the frame, but then add `startgamebutton` and `main` to the content pane, which is the same as adding it to the frame.  It's possible that `Start` is blocking the EDT, but don't have code for that.  The frame is likely using a `BorderLayout`, so only one component (probably `main`) is been managed by the layout manager, but you try and position the button using absolute positioning, which generally a bad idea ...

Comment: `Main` is an instance of `Canvas`, so now you're mixing light and heavy weight components, which never goes well, and are probably using a `BufferStrategy` of some kind, which makes Swing incompatible with it... so kind of mess really (no offence)

Comment: Yes I am using a BufferStrategy, and I did hear about heavy/lightweight components on other threads. I am planning on re-doing the frame but not sure at which direction I should head in. Should I completely remove canvas and replace it with JPanel? Also what is an alternative to BufferStrategy?

Comment: The answer will depend on what it is you're trying to achieve.  `BufferStrategy` will allow you control over the paint process (AKA active painting), but makes it incompatible with Swing components, which use a different painting process.  So do you need the access to the hardware acceleration of `BufferStrategy` (which semi negated by the fact that Swing is rendered on the back of OpenGL/DirectX) or the Swing API